# How to re-activate Windows 8 after entering wrong Windows 8 key?

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

I entered my PC's Win 8 pro product key into my laptop which was currently running Win 8 with the intention to switch my laptop to the pro version.

I do have a full back up of the whole drive of the laptop HDD but since they are in GPT and not MBR format, it is not very easy to recover all the data.

Is there a way to make windows reactivate to the standard windows 8?

**EDIT 1:** I cannot re-enter the key since i don't know it. Its a BIOS embedded key.

Comment: Put in the correct key

Comment: You can't use the same key on more than one PC.

Comment: What makes you say its not easy to recover GPT partitions?  I am shocked Windows Activation even allowed you to enter a Windows 8 Professional key while running Windows 8 Core.  What process did you use to change they key, that disregarded, the activation errors?  If You cannot install Professional over a Media Center installation I know the same to be true to be true for Core -> Professional.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change the key if you go to Start -> Run -> cmd.exe -> `slui 3` and try entering a different key.